# Using Photos Albums and enabling plupload, there's no way to upload

Tags: 8, media

I'm attempting to use photo albums to make a photo gallery. if I don't select the Plupload checkbox for file uploads, when I add content, I have the facility to upload 5 different files. When I select that checkbox, there's no actual way to upload the files anymore. I just see the screenshot I included.

I'm using 8.8.5 & Plupload 3.1.2, but even with Plupload 2.3.6 or 2.1.9 the result is the same. I don't see anything specifically enlightening in the JavaScript console.

[image: with plupload 3.1.2 enabled, no ability to select image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report or support request to a third-party project hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere and must be reported in its issue queue to track issues in a single place, not here.

Comment: it is supposed to be plupload 2.1.9 or higher which is why i tried so many versions. and i read the instructions and it says to only tag with 8 version tag if it's about 8 core. or that's what i thought it said

Comment: Where did you put the library?

Comment: the instructions said to put it in /web/libraries/plupload

Comment: btw, the reason i came here instead of plupload website is because this module is recommended off of the drupal.org website and also using plupload is the recommended configuration of the module page. it feels like there's some combo problem between plupload & Drupal. and the albums photos module has been around forever so i thought someone else may have seen this before.